# How to update my desktop application from a Windows Phone 7.5 Mobile application

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, windows-phone-7

Our desktop application require to be updated directly when a mobile employee sends any message from his/her windows phone 7 mobile.

Currently our requirement is that send a message from our desktop application to a Windows Phone 7.5 which we are able to achive easily using PUSH Notifications, Now when the user takes some action against the sent message the windows phone app calls the WCF service and pass the message to that WCF which receives the message and puts into the database and application reads it later and this is where problem lies. Because our WCF is putting that message into database our application is polling it every 5 second and if any replies received from any of our drivers then it is updating the UI.

What we want to achieve is when we receive any reply our desktop applicaton should be notified automatically and udpates the UI and then put it into the database.

So please share your experience on this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not update the WCF service to notify any registered "listeners" (i.e. running instances of your client app) that the database has been updated with new information?

You could do this by having your service expose a service that can be called by clients wanting to register for some/all event types. The client app(s) host a service implementing a callback contract that the service can call when the registered events are raised.

There's a good MSDN article one-way, callback and pub-sub messaging with WCF: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx.

Be sure to keep track of and throttle how many events your client app is receiving per second - the last thing you want to have happen is for 100 client apps to all hit the server 50 times each if 50 events are raised sumultaneously!

Comment: Richard, what you mean by client app, you mean our desktop application. if possible could you please ellaborate more your purposed solution, I am going through the mentioned article. I am new to WCF so I am sorry if I am asking silly question.

Comment: You mentioned a desktop application in your problem description. I assume that this "desktop app" (i.e. client app) will be the one registering for a callback when said event occurs and the server wants to notify the app that something has changed. Also, be sure to read that MSDN paper - it'll give you a lot of guidance on messaging topologies and solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Richard's solution is probably more proper, since it describes using nicely packaged WCF APIs that will do a lot for you. Another way could be to implement long-polling yourself. You could then also update your Windows Phone clients when they need to receive an immediate update. I wrote an [article](http://xyzzer.wordpress.com/2011/03/10/real-time-client-server-communication-on-windows-phone-with-long-polling/) on that some time ago which you can find if you google long polling on Windows Phone.